# Passthrought HTTP Status codes on a VPC Link integration type without using proxy integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a VPC Link GW on AWS, I cannot use proxy integration.

Currently, I'm having to add all the possible codes in method response and integration response. Otherwise it throws a 500 error.

Is there a way to simple pass through the status codes? I know using proxy integration does that but that is not possible in my situation.

I see a output passthrough section in integration response as shown in the image below. Any way to change it to yes? Or any other way to pass through the status codes?

[image]